# How to make a SwipeRefreshLayout doesn't trigger when I am using a Google map?

Tags: google-maps, android-studio, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am working in Android Studio, I have a SwipeRefreshLayout and inside this a WebvIew that loads a Google map, when I try to move around the map and I slide from above the WebView is updated making it impossible to use the map correctly, is there any way to solve this ?

The layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


    <WebView
android:id="@+id/mainWV"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" >

</WebView>
```

Comment: Were you able to find the solution for this?